# Unable to understand GCP bill for Stackdriver Monitoring usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kube-state-metrics

We have implemented kube-state metrics (by following the steps mentioned in this article section [4.4.1 Install monitoring components](https://medium.com/google-cloud/gke-monitoring-84170ea44833)) on one of our kubernetes clusters on GCP. So basically it created 3 new deployments node-exporter, prometheus-k8s and kube-state metrics on our cluster. After that, we were able to see all metrics inside Metric Explorer with prefix "external/prometheus/".

In order to check External metrics pricing, we referred to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#monitoring-costs). Hence, we calculated the price accordingly but when we received the bill it's a shocking figure. GCP has charged a lot of amount but we haven't added any single metric in dashboard or not set monitoring for anything. From the ingested volume (which is around 1.38GB/day), it looks these monitoring tools do some background job (at specific time it reads some metrics or so) which consumed this volume and we received this bill.

We would like to understand how these kube-state metrics monitoring components work. Will it automatically get metrics data and increase the ingested volume and bill in such way or there is any mis-configuration in its setup?

Any guidance on this would be really appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: kube-state-metrics is not installed or configured by
default when enabling Stackdriver Monitoring. You
only need to enable Stackdriver Monitoring on the
cluster. From there, you can choose which metrics
to monitor using the metrics explorer. You can read
more about kube-metrics-sever here [1].
[1] https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics

Comment: Thank you.. We are aware about its setup. Stackdriver Monitoring is already enabled on our cluster. But the question is how to calculate the total cost while using kube-state metrics on cluster. We have only installed its components and we have got a bill of thousands of dollar.

Answer (score 0):

By default, when implemented, kube-state-metrics exposes several metrics for events across your cluster:

If you have a number of frequently-updating resources on your cluster, you may find that a lot of data is ingested into these metrics which incurs high costs.

You need to [configure](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/cli-arguments.md) what metrics you'd like to expose, as well as consult the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_other) for your Kubernetes environment in order to avoid unexpected high costs.